# How to render multi code point emojis with Javascript

Tags: javascript, emoji

I am trying to render emojis in a chat app and am having trouble getting emojis that are constructed with multiple parts to work.

For example:

The code point `26f9` for `Person with Ball` works

```
const emoji = String.fromCodePoint('0x26f9');
```

But `26f9-fe0f-200d-2640-fe0f` for `Woman bouncing ball` does not work

```
const emoji = String.fromCodePoint('0x26f9-fe0f-200d-2640-fe0f');
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out:

```
const codePointString = '26f9-fe0f-200d-2640-fe0f';

const emoji = codePointString.split('-').map((codePoint) => (
  String.fromCodePoint(`0x${codePoint}`)
)).join('');
```

Comment: Thank you, I read way too much about this before finding this simple answer